# xsl:template match not working

Tags: diazo

I have an image (in the content) with a src attribute

```
http://myPage/rss.gif
```

I wan't to change the attribute. The xsl:template match expression doesn't work..

```
<replace css:content="#content" css:theme=".content" />
<xsl:template match="img/@src[contains(., 'rss.gif')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">/++theme++myPackage/images/<xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably get `++theme++myPackage/images/http://myPage/rss.gif`. Do you?

Comment: Hi...no I get nothing. It doesn't match. But the image exists -> <img src="https://mySite/news/rss.gif">

Answer (score 0):

In your example you select an `img`-tag containing the string `rss.gif` in its `src`-attribute, this string is probably `http://myPage/rss.gif`.

Then you add an attribute `src` to the `img`-tag beeing its value the concatenation of the strings `/++theme++myPackage/images/` and the original value `http://myPage/rss.gif`.

The original value is added by `<xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>`. This selects the whole value of the `src`-attribute!

Thus you get something like:

```
<img id="content" src="/++theme++myPackage/images/http://myPage/rss.gif" />
```

For test purposes you could first add an `img`-element whith the expected `src`-attribute to your theme.html file and check if the image file is accessed. Please check also that the value of `src` in your content file only contains the string that you want to append to `/++theme++myPackage/images/`.

BTW, in your example you replace the theme element by class: `css:theme=".content"`. Remind that this will replace all elements with the class `content`. Consider using id or a narrower selector e.g. `div.content` or better `div#someid.content`.